# Is there any way to modify log4j2 xml configuration's element programmatically?

Tags: log4j2

I'm trying to extend the `XMLConfiguration` class and change the pattern value in `PatternLayout` , but the change can't be made. The pattern remains with the old string.
Does log4j2 just enable the add/remove operations upon an existing static configuration XML file?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I have found that one way to do it is just to kind of traversing the `rootNode` and change the property you want , just before the `super.doConfigure()` call.
for example :

```
@Override
protected void doConfigure() {
  final String pattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}";
  if(getRootNode().getChildren() != null) {
     getRootNode().getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).setValue(pattern);
  }
  super.doConfigure();

}
```

Comment: Just be aware that doing this will make your code depend on the log4j2 implementation so long term maintenance could be problematic.

Comment: Sure. That is something which has been taken into consideration